# select one class from classes within the same attribute

Tags: jquery

I have some elements that when clicked will fire some action and select the "class" attribute.

in jQuery it's simple by using `$(this).attr('class')`

but the problem is that when we want to select one class from multiple classes like when we have for example:

```
<a href="#" class="class1 class2"></a>
```

and we want to get only the first class (class1) because when we use this: `$(this).attr('class')` we will get "class1 class2" as a result.

any idea?

Comment: Presumably you don't want to (or an not able to) use .hasClass() to detect if it has a specific class?

Comment: @John: the idea is to make a call for the content of a div that has the id which is the same as the first class of the clicked button and the 2nd class is for styling for example.

Comment: Can we see example code for that idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first class:

```
$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
```

However, the idea of classes is that they are *unordered*, hence there's no jQuery method to do this directly. You may wish to include a `data-` attribute instead:

```
<a href="#" class="class2" data-target="someId"></a>
```

With jQuery 1.4.3+ you can directly access the `data-target` attribute with:

```
$(this).data('target');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if their is a way to do this in jquery but i would just get the classes and then just use a split function and take the first item in the split array

```
$(this).attr('class')// which happens to have "class1 class2" in it

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");
mySplitResult[0] // should be "class1"
```

hope this helps

EDIT->> seems box9 beat me to it. nice work :)

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue today. Came up with a slightly different solution to deal with not knowing the order of the classes.

Still making the assumption that the class name (or some of it) is known I used a regular expression.

Get the list of classes as a string

```
var classList = $(this).attr('class');
```

returns something like "class-1 class-2 my-special-class-1 class-4"

```
var pattern = /\bmy-special-class-[0-9]+\b/;
```

In this case I want to find the class any classes that start with "my-special-class-" and end in a number

```
var matchResult = classList.match(pattern);
```

Check to see if there is a match(es). In my case I know there is only going to be one class with a number (that I dont know) at the end. I want to use this for a jquery call so I attached the "." to the string

```
if (matchResult) {
   var foundClass = "." + matchResult[0]; // assuming one class (loop for more)
   var elementsWithClass = $(foundClass);
}
```

Comment: provide some code preview or demo(jsFiddle) to describe your answer.